# Does a barbarian need to damage a target to keep Rage from ending, or just attack the target (whether or not it hits)?

Tags: dnd-5e, damage, attack, barbarian, rage

I’m playing DND 5e, the rage ability states that the effect ends early if your turn ends and you haven’t attacked a hostile creature since your last turn or taken damage since then.

Does this mean that the Barbarian has to DEAL damage to an opponent, or just use an attack action in general, and the hit landing not being a factor?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: The interesting corner case here is swinging wildly at square you think contains an invisible opponent.  It's an Attack, but is it against a "hostile opponent"?  You could go either way on that, either getting even more enraged at these shenanigans, or getting confused and your rage ending (if nothing is goading you with damage).

Comment: I don't know about you, but I would get even *more* mad if I missed who I was swinging at.  "RAH! Stand still, puny human!"

Answer (score 29):

> Your rage lasts for 1 minute. It ends early if you are knocked unconscious or if your turn ends and you haven’t **attacked a hostile creature** since your last turn or **taken damage** since then.

You just have to attack - that is, *try to* hit the enemy. Whether you succeed or not doesn't matter.

If you had to damage them, it would say so, like it does for taking damage yourself.